# Is it bad for the PowerSwitch Tail 2 to turn on and off frequently?

Tags: relay, ds18b20

I am using my Raspberry Pi with a PowerSwitch Tail 2 to control the temperature of homebrewed beer. Whenever the temperature goes above a certain range, the PST2 shuts off, and turns on when the temperature falls below a certain range.

Sometimes my temperature probes (DS18B20) will measure just above and just below a certain temperature, resulting in the PST2 turning on and off rapidly, making that large click sound that it does.

Will this result in a lower lifespan of the PST2? I started using a min and max temperature which is a 0.75*F difference to prevent this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A relay (which is what is creating the click sound) is a mechanical device and as a result can wear out. Though the service life is likely in the 100,000's or greater. so you will have to make the decision if this is something you are willing to chance for the perfect brew. When it fails it will kill the power to the heater, likely leaving you with bad bear and a dead powertail.

Having said that using it to control a very small temperature range may not be the best idea. To draw an analogy to a furnace or air conditioner they normally run slightly past the desired temperature to avoid cycling so often. for example if you set the furnace's thermostat to 65 degrees the system may not turn off until 67 degrees (instead of right at 65). The same thing happens as the house cools down it may let it get a degree or 2 cooler before turning on.

Since you are aiming for such a tight temperature range you may want to consider the effect of turning off the heating element. Many things will continue to get warmer before they begin to cool. So you may want to consider turning the heat off before you reach your upper bound but only testing can tell you if this is true for your setup.

Comment: Good point on the furnace analogy. At least with the 5 gallon batches I brew, my data points indeed show that the temperature exceeds my max/min range by 0.02F on occasion.

Comment: I'm assuming there is no way I can query the PST2 for "are you going to die soon?"? Perhaps someway I can manually test them between batches? Of course I can look at manufacturers specs (Life expectancy: 100,000 operations @ 15 amps, 125vac, resistive.), use my python program to count the number of on and off switches occur on average over a couple of batches and make some calculations (albeit I've had my PST2s for over a year now so that won't work now).

Comment: When the manufacturer states "100,000" operations, does that include both on and off switches?, or only on switches?

Comment: I don't know for sure but I would err on the side of caution and use the lower of the 2 numbers. Just because the specs says 100,000 doesn't mean it won't die at 75,000 or 125,000. The spec is based on an average across several parts and batches. If the load you are driving is AC I would look into solid state relays which may have a higher  life expectancy.

Comment: Hey Steve. Lets say a device will die at the 100,000th "operation". If the PST2 died, will the device shut off all power through the relay, or, if it died right after allowing power on, would the device continue to allow power on? I ask because if the temperature of the beer drops, it would only be classified as a bummer, whereas if the temperature of the beer continues to rise over a threshold, it would be classified as a catastrophic failure.

Comment: It is very unlikely to fail on, most likely if it failed it would fail off. I have a few other things for you to think about. Redundancy, and  location of the measurement. Right now you have one temperature sensor. where is the temp sensor (bottom, middle, top of your liquid/mash, or is it outside of the container. You are looking for a tight temperature range. and the location could explain a difference that big. What is the theoretical accuracy of your temp sensor (can it measure reliably that small a difference)?.

Comment: As for failure if you had two or more heating elements and 2 or more independent temp sensors you would build jn some redundancy.

Answer (score 0):

If you are controlling the relay through python, just build a delay (say about 30-60 seconds) before checking temp again - that should significantly reduce the number of cycles (operations), with minimal sacrifice to control of the temp  Good luck with the Brew !